# Regular expression for matching a sentence step by step

Tags: javascript, regex, cucumber, cucumberjs

Regular expression to match the below cucumber steps

```
Given I login to system
Given login to system

Given user attempts to login to system
Given I attempt to login to system
Given attempts to login to system
```

This one Should fail - user or I or BLANK are valid but not he or other words

```
Given he login to system
```

I tried the below one but no help.

```
 Given(/(?: user|I?)?(?: attempts to)? login to system/, function () {});
```

Comment: I tried the below one but no help.

```Given(/(?: user|I?)?(?: attempts to)? login to system/, function () {});```

Comment: `^Given(?: user| I)?(?: attempts? to)? login to system`?

Comment: @Gan You are expected to demonstrate your own attempts at solving this and then describe the specific problem you have, an obstacle you encountered.

Comment: @Yunnosch he did provide his attempt in the comments, which is more than some

Comment: @depperm Good point actually. I missed that. Sorry. However, hiding this kind of helpful information in comments can cause exactly that problem: being missed. Also, "no help" is not exactly an explanation of the problem. How did it fail? For which input does it give false positives or false negatives.

Comment: I copied the info from comment an deleted the three characters. Please [edit] yourself to fine tune. Also double check the `;` at the end of the shown coding attempt. It seems not to match your goal.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regex's at all when cuking. You will just make something vastly over complicated that can't possibly match all the different use cases your scenarios demand. Instead write a simple step definition for each one, and have each step definition call the same helper method to implement the functionality.

So you get

```
Given 'I login into the system' do
  login as: @i
end

Given 'Fred logs into the system' do
  login as: @fred
end

Given 'I login into the system as an admin' do
  login as: @i, role: 'admin'
end

...
```

This simplifies, is DRY enough and removes completely the need for regex's in your step definitions (note: I've been cuking from the very beginning and haven't used a regex for several years, they give no benefit at all), and encourages better code when implementing (that login function is going to be used extensively).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you might be trying to design an expression similar to:

```
^Given\s*(?:I|user)?\s*(?:attempts?\s+to)?\s*(?:login\s+to\s+system)$
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/GAXxzo/1/) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.